Is there any gnome extension to show notification when battery level exceed 80 percentage?
Ubuntu already have in-build notification for low battery (means when battery level is 20% or below the system will show notification)
However, there is no feature to show notification when battery level is 80% or above.
For maintaining a good battery health, experts are recommending to use the devices between 20% and 80%.
I haven't seen any in-build feature inside Ubuntu to do this and I could't able to find a gnome extension.
Is there any gnome extension available to achieve this?

I saw this while searching for one: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5724/battery-health-charging/

I use my Bash script setup to notify Battery charge/discharge percentage at certain intervals. Hope it can help you, you can customise the script to your needs. Here's the link.. Please comment if it helps.

@vtvinh24
Even though the extension you mentioned (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5724/battery-health-charging) is not for showing notification. but it is solving the core problem that I'm facing. Thanks for suggesting the extension.
